# how to assign another task when a component's function finishes in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my app I use `<AnimateNumber />` for a particular
animation but right when this process finishes i want to assign
some other task, and I want to do it when `<AnimateNumber />`
finishes how can I do that

**This is how I use it in my code**:

```js
render(){ 
return(
<Image >
.
.
.
<AnimateNumber />
.
.
</Image>
);
}
```

**So my process goes like this**:

1. screen loads
2. a number animation occurs

**and then,
I need to give a response to user right when this number animation finishes**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the prop :
**`onFinish={() => { console.log('done') }}`**

assign it whatever function you want to do inside **`onFinish`**

refer this: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-animate-number/blob/master/test/index.js